# Problems integrating function with two variables with singularity in one point (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I've been trying to integrate the function given in the code over "phi" and "r". Therefor I'm using the Matlab function "integral2". The function has a singularity at (r,phi)=(1,0) ([here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aClhh.jpg)), which lets the integrator reach the max possible function evaluations and yields and error. I guess this has not to do with the singularity itself but with the very steep descent next to it!?
I'd be happy for any suggestions on how to get the integration working!
Maybe another integrator or a substitution of variables?

Thanks a lot! :)

```
p = @(r) 1./sqrt(1-r.^2);
x = 1; 
z = 1e-12;
nu = .3;

X = @(r,phi) x-r.*cos(phi);
Y = @(r,phi) -r.*sin(phi);
R = @(r,phi) (X(r,phi).^2 + Y(r,phi).^2).^.5;
Rho = @(r,phi) (X(r,phi).^2 + Y(r,phi).^2 + z^2).^.5;

f1 = @(r,phi) (1 - z./Rho(r,phi)).*(X(r,phi).^2 - Y(r,phi).^2)./R(r,phi).^2;
f2 = @(r,phi) f1(r,phi) + z*Y(r,phi).^2./Rho(r,phi).^3;
f3 = @(r,phi) (1 - 2*nu)./R(r,phi).^2.*f2(r,phi) - 3*z*X(r,phi).^2./Rho(r,phi).^5;
fun = @(r,phi) r.*p(r).*f3(r,phi);

sx = 1/2/pi*integral2(fun,0,1,0,pi);
```

Comment: Have you tried symbolic integration? -- also, please format your code correctly, it's hard to read this way. You can [edit] your question, select the code, then click on the `{}` button.

Comment: Yes I've already tried that and it doesn't work. I guess there's no analytical solution to the integral..